# Inspector Rubberduck and the abstract inspections

Tags: c#, rubberduck

The Rubberduck code inspections have just seen yet another structural change, hopefully for the better.

The `IInspectionModel` interface was originally named `IInspection`; it only exposes the bare-bones inspection properties, those needed by the `CodeInspectionSetting` class:

```
public interface IInspectionModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the inspection type name.
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the inspection, without the "Inspection" suffix.
    /// </summary>
    string AnnotationName { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a short description for the code inspection.
    /// </summary>
    string Description { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating the type of the code inspection.
    /// </summary>
    CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating the severity level of the code inspection.
    /// </summary>
    CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }
}
```

The `CodeInspectionSetting` type is XML-serialized into the Rubberduck settings file; this allows us to let the user determine an inspection's `Severity` level:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class CodeInspectionSetting : IInspectionModel
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Description { get; set; } // not serialized because culture-dependent

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string AnnotationName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string SeverityLabel
    {
        get { return RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("CodeInspectionSeverity_" + Severity, RubberduckUI.Culture); }
        set
        {
            foreach (var severity in Enum.GetValues(typeof (CodeInspectionSeverity)))
            {
                if (value == RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("CodeInspectionSeverity_" + severity, RubberduckUI.Culture))
                {
                    Severity = (CodeInspectionSeverity)severity;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get; set; }

    public CodeInspectionSetting()
    {
        //default constructor required for serialization
    }

    public CodeInspectionSetting(string name, string description, CodeInspectionType type, CodeInspectionSeverity severity)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        InspectionType = type;
        Severity = severity;
    }

    public CodeInspectionSetting(IInspectionModel inspection)
        : this(inspection.Name, inspection.Description, inspection.InspectionType, inspection.Severity)
    { }
}
```

The `SeverityLabel` is used by the settings UI. Does it even belong there?

The `IInspection` interface exposes additional members, including a method responsible for returning actual inspection results (given a *parser state*, but that's now an implementation detail):

```
/// <summary>
/// An interface that abstracts a runnable code inspection.
/// </summary>
public interface IInspection : IInspectionModel, IComparable<IInspection>, IComparable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs code inspection on specified parse trees.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns inspection results, if any.</returns>
    IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a string that contains additional/meta information about an inspection.
    /// </summary>
    string Meta { get; }
}
```

Up until two days ago, every code inspection implemented `IInspection` directly. The recent changes introduce an abstract class, to help remove the redundant code that's common to all implementations:

```
public abstract class InspectionBase : IInspection
{
    protected readonly RubberduckParserState State;
    protected InspectionBase(RubberduckParserState state)
    {
        State = state;
    }

    public abstract string Description { get; }
    public abstract CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults();

    public virtual string Name { get { return GetType().Name; } }
    public virtual CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }
    public virtual string Meta { get { return InspectionsUI.ResourceManager.GetString(Name + "Meta"); } }
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global: it's referenced in xaml
    public virtual string InspectionTypeName { get { return InspectionsUI.ResourceManager.GetString(InspectionType.ToString()); } }
    public virtual string AnnotationName { get { return Name.Replace("Inspection", string.Empty); } }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<Declaration> Declarations
    {
        get { return State.AllDeclarations.Where(declaration => !declaration.IsInspectionDisabled(AnnotationName)); }
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<Declaration> UserDeclarations
    {
        get { return State.AllUserDeclarations.Where(declaration => !declaration.IsInspectionDisabled(AnnotationName)); }
    }

    public int CompareTo(IInspection other)
    {
        return string.Compare(InspectionType + Name, other.InspectionType + other.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return CompareTo(obj as IInspection);
    }
}
```

The main reason for introducing this base class, was to enable the `@Ignore {InspectionName}` annotations that the `IgnoreOnceQuickFix` is inserting, without having to specify in every single inspection that it needs to check for `IsInspectionDisabled(AnnotationName)`. Another reason was to avoid the redundant filtering on `!declaration.IsBuiltIn`, since most inspections operate on *user declarations* and their usages.

This is the quick fix class in question:

```
public class IgnoreOnceQuickFix : CodeInspectionQuickFix
{
    private readonly string _annotationText;
    private readonly string _inspectionName;

    public IgnoreOnceQuickFix(ParserRuleContext context, QualifiedSelection selection, string inspectionName) 
        : base(context, selection, InspectionsUI.IgnoreOnce)
    {
        _inspectionName = inspectionName;
        _annotationText = "'" + Parsing.Grammar.Annotations.AnnotationMarker +
                          Parsing.Grammar.Annotations.IgnoreInspection + ' ' + inspectionName;
    }

    public override bool CanFixInModule { get { return false; } } // not quite "once" if applied to entire module
    public override bool CanFixInProject { get { return false; } } // use "disable this inspection" instead of ignoring across the project

    public override void Fix()
    {
        var codeModule = Selection.QualifiedName.Component.CodeModule;
        var insertLine = Selection.Selection.StartLine;

        var codeLine = insertLine == 1 ? string.Empty : codeModule.get_Lines(insertLine - 1, 1);
        var annotationText = _annotationText;
        var ignoreAnnotation = "'" + Parsing.Grammar.Annotations.AnnotationMarker + Parsing.Grammar.Annotations.IgnoreInspection;

        int commentStart;
        if (codeLine.HasComment(out commentStart) && codeLine.Substring(commentStart).StartsWith(ignoreAnnotation))
        {
            annotationText = codeLine + ' ' + _inspectionName;
            codeModule.ReplaceLine(insertLine - 1, annotationText);
        }
        else
        {
            codeModule.InsertLines(insertLine, annotationText);
        }
    }
}
```

---

For context, here's an implementation - the `ImplicitPublicMemberInspection`, which finds public members without an explicit access modifier:

```
public sealed class ImplicitPublicMemberInspection : InspectionBase
{
    public ImplicitPublicMemberInspection(RubberduckParserState state)
        : base(state)
    {
        Severity = CodeInspectionSeverity.Warning;
    }

    public override string Description { get { return RubberduckUI.ImplicitPublicMember_; } }
    public override CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get { return CodeInspectionType.MaintainabilityAndReadabilityIssues; } }

    private static readonly DeclarationType[] ProcedureTypes = 
    {
        DeclarationType.Function,
        DeclarationType.Procedure,
        DeclarationType.PropertyGet,
        DeclarationType.PropertyLet,
        DeclarationType.PropertySet
    };

    public override IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults()
    {
        var issues = from item in UserDeclarations
                     where ProcedureTypes.Contains(item.DeclarationType)
                        && item.Accessibility == Accessibility.Implicit
                     let context = new QualifiedContext<ParserRuleContext>(item.QualifiedName, item.Context)
                     select new ImplicitPublicMemberInspectionResult(this, string.Format(Description, ((dynamic)context.Context).ambiguousIdentifier().GetText()), context);
        return issues;
    }
}
```

All inspection classes are `sealed`, and pass the `RubberduckParserState` dependency down the base type's constructor.

For completeness' sake, here's the accompanying `ImplicitPublicMemberInspectionResult` class:

```
public class ImplicitPublicMemberInspectionResult : CodeInspectionResultBase
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<CodeInspectionQuickFix> _quickFixes;

    public ImplicitPublicMemberInspectionResult(IInspection inspection, string result, QualifiedContext<ParserRuleContext> qualifiedContext)
        : base(inspection, result, qualifiedContext.ModuleName, qualifiedContext.Context)
    {
        _quickFixes = new CodeInspectionQuickFix[]
        {
            new SpecifyExplicitPublicModifierQuickFix(Context, QualifiedSelection), 
            new IgnoreOnceQuickFix(qualifiedContext.Context, QualifiedSelection, Inspection.AnnotationName), 
        };
    }

    public override IEnumerable<CodeInspectionQuickFix> QuickFixes { get { return _quickFixes; } }
}
```

All inspection results that can be *ignored once* have an `IgnoreOnceQuickFix`; Rubberduck uses this list of quick-fixes to dynamically populate a menu in the code inspection window's toolbar.

---

Since I introduced the base/abstract class Something doesn't feel right anymore about `IInspection`: am I right to think it has become superfluous? The base class should simply implement `IInspectionModel`, and `IInspection` could be removed - and heck, `IInspectionModel` could then be renamed back to `IInspection` as it originally was called. It really feels like `CodeInspectionSetting` knows more than it needs to about an inspection.

Anything else jumps at you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple minor suggestions...

I'd introduce some extension methods to give the common predicates on collections of declarations somewhere to live:

```
public static class DeclarationsPredicates
{
     public static IEnumerable<Declaration> WhichAreUserDeclarations(this IEnumerable<Declaration> source)
     {
         if (source == null)
         {
             // throw an error or sneakily coerce to Enumerable.Empty<Declaration>();
         }

         return source.Where(declaration => !declaration.IsBuiltIn);
     }

     public static IEnumerable<Declaration> WhereInspectionIsNotDisabledByAnnotation(
         this IEnumerable<Declaration> source,
         string annotationName)
     {
         if (source == null)
         {
             // throw an error or sneakily coerce to Enumerable.Empty<Declaration>();
         }

         return source.Where(declaration => !declaration.IsInspectionDisabled(annotationName));
     }
}
```

I'm sure there are others that you'd find useful! You could now rewrite your properties as:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<Declaration> Declarations
{
    get { return State.AllDeclarations.WhereInspectionIsNotDisabledByAnnotation(AnnotationName); }
}

protected virtual IEnumerable<Declaration> UserDeclarations
{
    get { return State.AllUserDeclarations.WhereInspectionIsNotDisabledByAnnotation(AnnotationName); }
}
```

I think that's better because you've centralised your logic (I'm not overly fond of the name though). You could potentially remove the `.IsInspectionDisabled()` method from `Declaration` and put the logic in the extension method but that's up to you.

---

This is interesting `((dynamic)context.Context)`... Why are you doing that?

---

I agree that `SeverityLabel` definitely doesn't fit ;) I'd expect it to be readonly anyway:

```
// C#6
public string SeverityLabel => RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("CodeInspectionSeverity_" + Severity, RubberduckUI.Culture);
```

If you want to change the label, you should have to change the severity!

---

You have a lot of magic strings around the place:

"Inspection", "Meta", "CodeInspectionSeverity_"... They should be well named constants.

---

The trailing underscore in this name looks odd to me:

```
RubberduckUI.ImplicitPublicMember_
```

I'm guessing that the string is `"ImplicitPublicMember_"`? Either way, chop the underscore off.

---

This method is named in camelCase but should be PascalCase `ambiguousIdentifier()`

---

This property name doesn't look quite right:

```
 string Meta { get; }
```

I think it should be `Metadata`.

---

Your doc comment here isn't quite right:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a value indicating the severity level of the code inspection.
/// </summary>
CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }
```

It actually gets or sets a value...

There's also the [`<value>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azda5z79.aspx) tag that you should add. I use the [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) extension to help generate code documentation - that might help you out too.

---

I agree with your summary at the end - I'd drop back to just using an `ICodeInspection` interface. I changed the name because I don't like the double I in `IInspection` and it's also a little more descriptive.

On the whole - very nice!

Comment: Nice answer! The `dynamic` cast and `camelCase` methods are ANTLR limitations: the types that expose an `ambiguousIdentifier` method are generated, and they don't share a common interface. ANTLR parser rules must start with a lowercase, lexer rules with an uppercase - ANTLR generates classes and methods off a grammar definition that must follow this convention.

Comment: As for the trailing underscore, it's a visual cue I'm using to mean "this resource string contains a `{0}` placeholder that must be formatted". Not sure I'm ready to drop it, although I agree it looks a bit weird.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - generated code can be so frustrating like that ;) I'd replace that underscore with the word `Format`